# A problem with the resource function PacletizeResourceFunction

Tags: paclets

I recently tried to pacletize the resource function `SymbolToSubscript` using the resource function `PacletizeResourceFunction`, but it doesn't work with `SymbolToSubscript`.

Could someone explain to me what is happening?

Problems:

```
Import::chtype: First argument <<1>> is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification.

Insert::ins: Cannot insert at position {2} in $Failed

First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[None].

First::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[None].

Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: com.wolfram.paclet.PacletInfoException: VersionNumber does not have the correct form of digits separated by periods in paclet named SymbolToSubscript
at com.wolfram.paclet.impl.PacletInfo.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.wolfram.paclet.PacletFactory.createPacletInfos(Unknown Source)
at com.wolfram.paclet.PacletFactory.createPacletInfos(Unknown Source)
at com.wolfram.paclet.PacletPacker.pack(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566).
```

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: My Mathematica version: `13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)`

Comment: Can you give some more details on the kind of issue that you are experiencing? I tried with both `"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"` and `"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"`, and both paclet file generation and direct installation work without issues. I also tried to use the installed function, and all examples from the documentation appear to work as expected.

Comment: I was about to comment that problems with a resource function might not be on topic here and should go to the function author. Then I saw the comments above....from the function author.

Comment: It's probably easier to [continue this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139101/pacletizeresourcefunction-issues)

Comment: @LukasLang The problem persists even when changing the version. This did not happen until I updated `SymbolToSubscript`. I appreciate the time you took to reply.

Comment: @LukasLang I followed your instructions, and it solved the problem. I think you should include that suggestion as an answer, as it may be helpful to other users with the same problem. Thank you for your attention and patience in answering my question. Greetings! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this seems to have solved the issue according to the comments:

Since all other functions work on your machine, and the problematic function works on other computers, you can try to evaluate

```
ResourceRemove@ResourceFunction["SymbolToSubscript"]
```

This will remove any local versions of the problematic resource function, forcing Mathematica to redownload the latest version from the repository. My guess is that while developing and testing the function, you ended up with a locally deployed version of the function. `PacletizeResourceFunction` cannot work with that, since some information is missing in that case. (Usually, it should produce a more readable error message in this case, but somehow this didn't work in this instance)